# How do I prevent ice cubes from jamming in my ice maker?

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker

I have a Bosch fridge.  It has an ice maker in the freezer section.  Ice will frequently block the little fingers from ejecting ice into the container, like this:

[image]

Seven times a day I reach in and pull out a cube.  Assorted sizes, assorted finger positions.

What's the solution?  Yes, the fridge is level.  Well, it depends on where I hold the level.  Along the door jamb it is level.  The shelves are level, but not the roof.  What's the trick there?

Comment: possibly a bad ice maker design ... talk to Bosch

Comment: Why do you guys enjoy editing other people's posts to make them sound so robotic?

Comment: you think that removing bad grammar and spelling mistakes from your post makes it sound robotic?

Comment: @jsotola "Domo arigato, Mr. Roboto,"

Comment: "*How do I prevent ice cubes from jamming in my ice maker?*"  Is that Grateful Dead type jamming (*Wake up to find out that you are the ice of the world*)  or more extemporaneous jazz type jamming?  Cool Daddy-o.

Comment: @AlaskaMan now I'm going to be humming and whistling that catchy Styx tune for the next two days or longer ... lol

Comment: "*How do  I prevent ice cubes from jamming in my ice maker?*"  Take away their instruments.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there is frost build up in and around the fingers/fins that the ice is being pushed up through. (*and in and around the whole unit*)

The ice cubes are a specific size  and the fins/fingers that they are pushed up through are sized just right to allow the ice cubes to pass through.  If frost builds up on the fins then the size of the space/opening between them is altered.

I would suggest that you unplug your freezer  for at 24 hours with the door open to let it defrost.